# CodeActivity GetExtension null

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm

Saying that i never used Workflow and i started coding from a sample, i have a problem with the CodeActivityContext.GetExtension<> function.

This is the constructor

```
public SendReportMethod(Guid var1, string var2)
{
    this.var1= var1;
    this.var2= var2;
}
```

And this is the piece of code giving me the error:

```
protected override void Execute(CodeActivityContext  executionContext)
{
    IWorkflowContext context = executionContext.GetExtension<IWorkflowContext>();
    IOrganizationServiceFactory serviceFactory = executionContext.GetExtension<IOrganizationServiceFactory>();
    IOrganizationService service = serviceFactory.CreateOrganizationService(context.UserId);
}
```

Variables are all null, and the last one is obiouvsly giving me nullPointer.

This is the way i'm calling the CodeActivity:

```
WorkflowInvoker.Invoke(new SendReportMethod(interventionID, codiceFornitore));
```

What i'm doing wrong? any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are using Dynamics CRM, and you want to use a custom workflow activity in your workflows. Here's an example of how you would do that (found at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334455.aspx)

Also, here's a more comprehensive example: https://www.credera.com/blog/technology-insights/microsoft-solutions/three-essential-custom-workflow-activities-crm-2013/

```
public sealed class SimpleSdkActivity : CodeActivity
{
    [Input("Account Name")]
    [Default("Test Account")]
    public InArgument<string> AccountName { get; set; }
    protected override void Execute(CodeActivityContext executionContext)
    {
        //Create the tracing service
        ITracingService tracingService = executionContext.GetExtension<ITracingService>();

        //Create the context
        IWorkflowContext context = executionContext.GetExtension<IWorkflowContext>();
        IOrganizationServiceFactory serviceFactory = executionContext.GetExtension<IOrganizationServiceFactory>();
        IOrganizationService service = serviceFactory.CreateOrganizationService(context.UserId);

        var entityName = AccountName.Get<string>(executionContext);
    }
}
```